# problem with submitting an app for review

Tags: ios, app-store

When I submit an iOS app for review, we are getting the following message.

"An unexpected error was encountered when submitting for review. If the issue persists please contact us"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case. I had to add at least one apple ID or organization ID in the private distribution section.

[image]